# get insights data of facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get insights data of a facebook page. I have tried with graph api with this url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/149279625121774/insights/?access_token=XXXX
```

but it gives empty data:

```
{    "data": [
          ],    "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/149279625121774/insights/...",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/149279625121774/insights/..." 
     } 
}
```

'149279625121774' is the page id.

Is anybody help me for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**
[`Insights`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/) can be retrieved only as an array. To read `Insights` you need

- a generic `access_token` for the publicly available `application_active_users` metric
- a generic app `access_token` for all `Insights` for that app
- `read_insights` [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) for all apps, pages and domains owned by this user

For more details on which insights are available please review the [FQL Insights table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/)

---

Here are my comments:

1. Most likely you don't have the [`read_insights`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) permission.
2. The user authenticated ***should*** be the owner/admin of the page!
3. Remove the trailing slash **`/`**

Comment: how can i check and enable read_insights permission in my facebook page?

Comment: you can check that from facebook privacy settings of your account and then applications settings. also you can ask for the extra permission from the login button/URL check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814432/facebook-sharing-graph-api), instead of `offline_access` use `read_insights`

Comment: Is not helpful for me. Works only if I specify metric names separated by coma: /{pageId}/insights/{metric1,metric2,...,metricN}

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

You must change the order of the scope parameter:

Try

```
email,read_insights,manage_pages
```

Instead of

```
email,manage_pages,read_insights
```

Comment: It would help if the downvoter commented something. This solution worked for me. The Graph API started to work after I moved manage_pages before read_insights.