# How to Post to My Facebook Fan Page using PHP and Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i like to post to my FB Fan Page, Some Content using cron job in PHP,How can i do that?
Can you gave me example?

Comment: Are you familiar with Facebook's Graph API?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814432/facebook-sharing-graph-api/4816134#4816134

Comment: It is different since @Alex is wanting to post to a FB Fan Page via an Application. You can see his desires in the below dialogue, but I agree that the question should be reworded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After becoming familiar with the Graph API check out Facebook's documentation for Pages
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

Here is the main page for Facebook's Graph API documentation
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

For PHP Development, check out this SDK, It will make your life much easier for interacting with Facebook using PHP
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/

Here is a link for how to configure your Facebook APP to be able to post on a Facebook Page
http://blog.theunical.com/facebook-integration/5-steps-to-publish-on-a-facebook-wall-using-php/
(I did not follow this exact tutorial but slaved to figure it out myself, so let me know how it works for you)

**note** As I mentioned in a below comment make special note of the permanent session key.

Comment: I know it's a large amount of information. But I highly recommend reading through it for a while, as well as checking out the PHP SDK that I posted. Then If you still have problems just let me know.

Comment: There is a bit of a learning curve so don't be discouraged if you don't immediately get it working :)

Comment: @KennyCason : i go through that pages early, for the past 2 days i am working on it, and i am getting noting.what i am trying to do is creating a Page and App, with the help of app some datas will be posted on the Page thats all..what all persmissions i need, offline access is a must?? can you gave me a sample code?

Comment: Now, an application and a page are two different things. So what exactly are you wanting to do? and yes, if you want it to work even when you're not logged in you need offline_access, and you must also store the offline_access token in your Database somewhere

Comment: have you looked at the PHP SDK I posted? It makes implementing the Graph API very easy.

Comment: Can u tell me how can i do that? what i need is like this, i have a page and by the help of my app..i can automatically print the news coming in the DB to the APP and post to my Page, so that i need to update only the DB,no need to Update the Fan Page all the time..by log in

Comment: Let's take steps. before working on making it work offline, let's try just getting a simple API call to post to the page while you're logged in

Comment: Ya i am using that PHP SDK,the problem i am facing is {"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."}}

Comment: yeah, that means that the user is not logged in

Comment: how can i make the user logged in?

Comment: Buy using the Example on the Bottom of the Link, i can able to post the message http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/

Comment: Ok so to clarify. You want your APP to post to the facebook page OR any user to be able to post to the page

Comment: If you want your app to publish to the facebook page you have a bit more work to do :)

Comment: Ok, awesome, that is definitely a bit hairier than just having a user post to the facebook page. Check out the new link I posted and make sure that you followed a similar process and/or let me know what you have done differently

Comment: ya i got the permanent session key, the problem is this is REST Call and the File they are gaving there is not able to extract

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean by "File they are gaving there is not able to extract", and the whole FB API is a REST API

Comment: be sure that you are passing the access_token along with the api call, otherwise i'm not sure why you would be getting an OAuthException, if you do indeed have a valid access_token. In fact try to log the access_token to make sure that one is even set

Comment: Keep playing around with it, and if you haven't figured it out by the time I get off work, I'll try to whip up an example

Comment: thks..an example to post to page will be a great help

Comment: I'm at work and can't access my code/server until I get home. so in the mean time keep trying :)