# FACEBOOK GRAPH/rest api: how to LOGIN my OWN USER to update my STATUS with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-rest-api

I want to update the status of a FAN-PAGE by PHP with the help of the Facebook graph api. google says: doesn't work.

Now I want to update my own user status by PHP. My main problem is how to login my own user to the graph api (with PHP), without using a browser and without funny PHP workarounds.

Comment: "i only wanted to update the **status of a FAN-PAGE**" vs "to update **my STATUS**" huh?

Comment: i have got a main facebook (user) page and an own fan-page, at the users account

Comment: @alex: so? whose page you want to publish to?

Comment: is using the **deprecated** rest api a requirement?

Comment: @ifaour: uhm, when rest api was deprecated? It is not deprecated.

Comment: @zerkms: sorry, it's not *totally* deprecated, most basic functions still works and still it's not a good idea to build new Apps using it.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases you need to get `publish_stream` permission http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

This can be done with [FB.login()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login)

More information: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication

After that you can just update status with graph api post: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post

Comment: and the login with FB.login is unlimited valid?

Comment: @alex: have you read the links I gave? `publish_stream  Enables your application to post content, comments, and likes to a user's stream and to the streams of the user's friends. With this permission, you can publish content to a user's feed at any time, without requiring offline_access. However, please note that Facebook recommends a user-initiated sharing model.` The permission is unlimited, the tokens are short-live ones. But you can always retrieve new.

Comment: "But you can always retrieve new" - how to do with php?

Comment: @alex: take official PHP SDK https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/ and it will do all the work for you. Btw, all the process is described on authentication link. **Please do read it**.

Comment: ok, when this all should work: please show me some working code. i have read the documentations the last day 100 times.

Comment: @alex: read once again, until you get it. What actually have you tried? Give us some code.

Answer (score 1):

> my main problem is how to login my own
>   user to the graph api (with php),
>   without using a browser and without
>   funny php workarounds.

<strike>There's *no way* for you to act on behalf of a user (even your own user) without interacting with him through a browser at least once to get the `offline_access`.</strike>

How to get the `offline_access` permission and how to use it from there onward is explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814432/facebook-sharing-graph-api/4816134#4816134).

**EDIT:**
Please read the comments! thanks @zerkms!

Comment: There is a way. It is in my answer. "You still need the publish_stream to post to your wall, even with the offline_access" this is just wrong. I use `publish_stream` **without** `offline_access`.

Comment: @zerkms: please read the question and the whole discussion on that answer..the user **doesn't** want to re-ask the user to login to post on his behalf everytime, this is why you **need** the `offline_access` for that. And I guess this is the case here too, since he doesn't want to use a browser!

Comment: @ifaour: yes, I know that. But for publishing **without** browser and any user interaction you don't need `offline_access`. My applications work with only `publish_stream` permitted. What did I miss and what am I doning wrong? ;-))

Comment: @ifaour: also, please read the documentation: With this permission, you can publish content to a user's feed at any time, **without requiring offline_access**. So, was you wrong or not? ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: I *guess* the documentation is misleading. try downloading the php-sdk, get the `publish_stream` perm, save the `access_token`, **logout**, and try using that `access_token`...you'll get *Error validating access token.*!

Comment: @zerkms: you are saying, your apps work with only `publish_stream` can you share with us your code? and BTW, when requesting the `publish_stream` the `expires` parameter returns a number and *NOT* zero like the `offline_access`.

Comment: ok, when this all should work: please show me some working code. i have read the documentations the last day 100 times.

Comment: @ifaour: http://pastebin.com/3jga8XaZ this is how I get permission. `save the access_token` for what purposes??? you don't need user's `access_token` to publish the stream. Since your application **has** the publish_stream permission you **don't need** access_token, which is, yes, temporary.

Comment: `$fb->api(array(
   'method' => 'stream.publish',
   'message' => $message->get_data('text'),
   'attachment' => $attachment,
   'uid' => $this->credentials
  ));` --- this is complete code to post, **without any tokens specifications**

Comment: @zerkms: this is only when you have a valid session! the SDK will take care of the `access_token` for you. But if the user **logout** you will not be able to post or act on his behalf until he login again or get `offline_access` and use the `access_token` returned!

Comment: @ifaour: lol. Dude, again: you don't need valid user session to post message for user who gave `publish_stream`. Just try it. And after user gave you that permission it doesn't matter either user logged in or not. You can beleve me, or not, but I have 4 applications that works in this way for > than one year. Probably I just made this some magic pixie dust, or just documentation is valid. ;-))

Comment: @zerkms: I did test what you said! it doesn't work and I can't see why it should work if the user is not logged in! and the code you posted in pastebin proves that you are asking the user to login so you can publish. can you setup a small (complete) example of what you are saying?

Comment: @ifaour: http://f-acebook-outer.zerkms.ru/pixie-dust.php --- post something here. http://www.facebook.com/pages/zerkms/126517520698090?v=wall --- here is the wall it is posted to. http://pastebin.com/R9UtW0Nf - here is the **complete** source.

Comment: @zerkms: LOL, I seriously think that you need to read the documentation again. read the last post in the page wall ;-)

Comment: @ifaour: ???? I've read it. So? That is what OP actually need, **without** `offline_access`.

Comment: "i only wanted to update the status of a FAN-PAGE by php with the help of the facebook graph api. " --- this is what OP wants. And this is what I actually do - I update status of fan page WITHOUT `offline_access`. any qustions? ;-)

Comment: Pages are not the same as users, how can you answer this question: `ok, now i only want to update my own user status by php. my main problem is how to login my own user to the graph api (with php), without using a browser and without funny php workarounds.` ? :-)

Comment: @ifaour: it can be done in the absolutely same way, dude ;-) Just ask `publish_stream` permission for user, not for page ;-) And after that you can post whenever you want.

Comment: @ifaour: http://www.facebook.com/zerkms --- look at my wall. It was posted with `$res = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'stream.publish', 'message' => $_POST['msg'], 'uid' => '636774153'));` without offline_access and WITHOUT active session ;-) http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4486681/zerkms_wall.png --- here is the wall screenshot if it is not accessible for non-friends.

Comment: @zerkms: that is odd! it seems that the SDK was throwing errors about the `CA` when `access_token` is not provided, fixed that and you are totally RIGHT! gonna leave the answer for people to learn from my mistakes!

Answer (score 1):

You need several things to update your facebook profile or a page's feed: a facebook application (**client_id**, **client_secret**), **profile_id**, and **access_token** (publish_stream, manage_pages, offline_access permissions)

You need offline_access because if not, then the access token will expire. If you've read that you don't need offline_access if you already have publish_stream specified, they just meant that you don't need it always.

To publish a post is easy:

```
$data = array(
    'access_token' => $access_token,
    'message' => 'status message',
    );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/{$profile_id}/feed");
```

Now how to get the **profile_id** and **access_token**, you can use my app [post panda](http://codecri.me/projects/post-panda/), or make your own script. I'll include it here:

```
# arvin castro
# http://codecri.me/
# January 16, 2011

$client_id     = ''; # application id
$client_secret = ''; # application secret
$callbackURL   = 'http://'; # the URL of this script
$extendedPermissions = 'publish_stream,manage_pages,offline_access';

session_name('facebookoauth');
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['logout']) and $_SESSION['loggedin']) {
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
}

if(isset($_GET['signin'])) {

    # STEP 1: Redirect user to Facebook, to grant permission for our application
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?' . xhttp::toQueryString(array(
        'client_id'    => $client_id,
        'redirect_uri' => $callbackURL,
        'scope'        => $extendedPermissions,
    ));
    header("Location: $url", 303);
    die();
}

if(isset($_GET['code'])) {

    # STEP 2: Exchange the code that we have for an access token
    $data = array();
    $data['get'] = array(
        'client_id'     => $client_id,
        'client_secret' => $client_secret,
        'code'      => $_GET['code'],
        'redirect_uri'  => $callbackURL,
        );

    $response = xhttp::fetch('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token', $data);

    if($response['successful']) {

        $var = xhttp::toQueryArray($response['body']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $var['access_token'];
        $_SESSION['loggedin']     = true;

    } else {
        print_r($response['body']);
    }
}

if($_SESSION['loggedin']) {
    // Get Profile ID
    $data = array();
    $data['get'] = array(
            'access_token'  => $_SESSION['access_token'],
            'fields' => 'id,name,accounts',
            );  
    $response = xhttp::fetch('https://graph.facebook.com/me', $data);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(json_decode($response['body'], true));
    echo '</pre>';

} else {
    echo '<a href="?signin">Sign in with Facebook</a>';
}

?>
```

I'm using my cURL wrapper class, [xhttp](http://codecri.me/sources/includes/class-xhttp-php/)

Comment: Or you can just mail('fanpageuploademail@m.facebook.com', 'status message', '');