# How to post to user's wall without logging in, using the new Facebook API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have stored a Facebook user ID and a Facebook friend ID. How can I publish to the user's wall without logging into Facebook?

I have used the old Facebook API that has UID and target_id fields like this:

```
$param  =   array(
    'method'        =>  'stream.publish',
    'callback'      =>  '',
    'message'       =>  $row[message], 
    'attachment'    =>  json_encode($attachment), 
    'target_id'     =>  $row[friends_id],
    'uid'           =>  $row[sender_id],
    'privacy'       =>  ''
);

$result = $facebook->api($param);
```

Is this possible in new facebook PHP API?

```
$attachment = array('message' => $wall);
$facebook->api("/$target/feed/",'post', $attachment);
```

The application has wall posting permissions.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I fixed your post for you - don't indent paragraphs you want to show as normal text, they become code instead. Also in the future, I recommend you capitalize your `I`'s - lack of that pakes the post look low quality, and  attracts downvotes.

Comment: @Pekka: So does spelling "makes" with a "p" :D

Comment: @fatty pilence! That was ... intentional. Art, you know.

Comment: Hey newbie, don't argue with @Pekka! :D Welcome to SO!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Publishing To User's Wall Without Being Online/Logged-in - Facebook Sharing Using Graph API](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4814432/publishing-to-users-wall-without-being-online-logged-in-facebook-sharing-using)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is possible only if you have the access_token with offline_permission granted.
if you have it, then include the token in  $attachment with key "access_token"

Comment: without offline_access permission, it is impossible for something to posting to a user wall programmatically!  The question has stated clearly that he wants to do it via facebook api.   

So, using FB.ui etc to bring up the feed dialog is not something that addresses the question

Comment: No it's not impossible, please refer to the same discussion I had before in the comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860906/facebook-graph-rest-api-how-to-login-my-own-user-to-update-my-status-with-php/4861166#4861166) it's good to learn new things from the community :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs it's also possible to post to a users feed without the "offline_permission" when the "publish_stream" permission is granted:

Comment about "publish_stream" taken from the docs:
Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's stream and to the streams of the user's friends. With this permission, you can publish content to a user's feed at any time, without requiring offline_access.

Comment: you can do publishing at any time w/ "publish_stream"... but for that the user has to be logged in.  The question is asking for how to do the publishing w/o logged in.