# Auto post stream (feed) to app users

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

How can i post stream (`$facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', $attachment);`) to my app users on anytime. I think i can get access token via `$facebook->getAccessToken();` but after, how can i post to wall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grant the `publish_stream` permission and use the user id after that instead of `me`:

```
$facebook->api("/$user_id/feed", 'post', $attachment);
```

For more information, check the last edit (**EDIT 4**) on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814432/facebook-sharing-graph-api/4816134#4816134) (also follow the discussion on the other answer that I linked to there).

Answer (score 0):

**First:** See if the session is valid

```
if ($session) {
    try {
     $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
```

**Second - IF** it is valid, you will make the API call to post

```
       $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array(
    'message'=> 'Sample Message', 
    'picture' => 'URL of Picture', 
    'link'=> 'URL',
    'description'=>'Description',
    'name'=> 'Name of Post',
    'privacy'=> 'privacy',
    'caption'=>'Caption',                                                                ) );
 } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
      }
    }
```

It's simple, just copy all the code you see above, it should work out the box.