# Automatic FB wall posting

Tags: php, facebook

I do have website for Hotel which has facebook registration module for the users to register. There are two kinds of user for my website, one is normal registered user and second user is Facebook Registered user. This seems to work correctly upto this moment.In the website, all the users are allowed to post their own review about hotels,favorites etc.

I need a way for automatic sharing (posting )of reviews, likes and favourites to the users Facebook friends in the Facebook website.If any users write some reviews this need to be automatically posted to the Facebook wall. Is there is any php-Facebook plugin to meet this requirement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto post stream (feed) to app users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945838/auto-post-stream-feed-to-app-users)

Answer (score 0):

Automatically posting to peoples Facebook wall is a quick was to get people to stop using your site.  I assume you are using the facebook php-sdk to do your login?  You need to get offline_access and publish_stream permissions http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

With that, you can then write to the users wall using the permanent access token.  See the publishing section [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Comment: @Gazler: Sure. no need for the `offline_access` permission. Please follow the answer I posted as duplicate.

Comment: Hmm, that depends on if he wishes to post periodically, or only when the user is online.  But after re-reading, looks like you are correct.

Comment: @Gazler: even if the user is not online, this will remain true. I learned the hard way too (if you follow the answers I posted and read the comment on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860906/facebook-graph-rest-api-how-to-login-my-own-user-to-update-my-status-with-php/4861166#4861166) ) you'll notice that I was convinced that you need the `offline_access` too! :-) I learned the hard way I guess.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for pointing that out.  I have only used the publish_stream permission before.

Comment: @Gazler : Can you please provide any sample tutorials for the offline_access which would be very helpful for me.