# How to Post facebook wall automatically with Facebook API (only with userid)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

using fconnect user have authenticated and i have saved their userid to my database.

When i try to publish to their wall is redirecting to Facebook login page . If user haven't logged in.

```
$status = $facebook->api('/MY_USER_ID/feed', 'POST', 
   array('message' => 'This post came from my app.'));
```

Help me but some web app are posting status to my wall without even i havn't logged into facebook.

Please help me to fix it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below code helps you to get permissions from user and access the user's information:

```
$dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=". $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&scope=publish_stream,user_about_me,read_friendlists,offline_access,publish_actions,friends_photos,,user_photos". "&state=" . $_SESSION['state'];

echo("<script> window.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
```

Answer (score 1):

When your application gets permissions from the user you need to specify you need the offline_access permission using the scope parameter.

Comment: how to add scope parameter ?  i am using $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); to redirect to facebook if the user have not authenticated.

Comment: Try this for fbconnect:  FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("offline_access");

Comment: fconnect is not the same as fbconnect. I fail

Comment: i am using php , so please help me :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to ask for the `publish_stream` permission and then your code will work. For more about this check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814432/facebook-sharing-graph-api/4816134#4816134) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935979/facebook-apps-additional-permissions/4936270#4936270) answers.

Comment: still my page is redirect to facebook login page,

Comment: and some time getting error Uncaught OAuthException: (#506) Duplicate status message thrown