# How to get json response data using facebook graph api 2.5?

Tags: java, facebook

I have a code that brings the json response from the twitter api. I want to use same code for facebook graph api to get json response from the Facebook but facebook doesn't provide any consumer keys as twitter. I can change this code to get the facebook json response. Can any of you help to modify the code.

```
public class TwitterResponse {

  static String AccessToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  static String AccessSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  static String ConsumerKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  static String ConsumerSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

  /**
   * @param args
   */

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    OAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(ConsumerKey,ConsumerSecret);
    String twitterUrl="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=heymailme143&count=1&include_rts=true&contributors=true";

    consumer.setTokenWithSecret(AccessToken, AccessSecret);

    //HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json");
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(twitter);

    consumer.sign(request);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    String m=IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent());
    System.out.println(m);
    System.out.println(statusCode + ":" + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
  }
}
```

This is a sample code I used to get the twitter response. Could you help me in changing it to get the facebook response using fb graph api?

Comment: have you the permission from user to access his personal details?

Comment: refer my answer to get the permission from user.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127527/how-to-post-facebook-wall-automatically-with-facebook-api-only-with-userid/10045798#10045798

Comment: sorry i didn't get you ! are you saying me to have the permissions from the user before i get the data of him ?@khAn

Comment: Yes, If you want to get the Info of user, you need to take the permission of user,see my first comment.

Comment: so I can't fetch the data of user with-out his/her permission but in twitter we can fetch the user data without permission of persons.okay thank you :) @khAn

Comment: That's not correct because Twitter is also using OAuth Access Tokens. An Access Token is practically a set of permissions granted by a specific user. Your question is much too broad BTW...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

- http://facebook4j.org/en/index.html

which also has some [examples](http://facebook4j.org/en/code-examples.html).

Comment: I want json response according to my knowledge  FB4J gives the required fields only not the json response i think @Tobi

Comment: What do you even mean? And what kind of sense does it make to have plain text JSON if you're using Java?

Comment: I’m looking for the json response @Tobi

Answer (score 0):

I'm Looking for this :)

```
public String getUserInfo(String access_token) throws MalformedURLException, ProtocolException, IOException {
    try {
        String connection = connectionGet("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + access_token, "");


        System.out.println("done");
        return connection;

    } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println("null value");
       return null;
    }
}


public static String connectionGet(String url, String parameter) throws MalformedURLException, ProtocolException, IOException {

    URL url1 = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection request1 = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
    request1.setRequestMethod("GET");
    request1.connect();
    String responseBody = convertStreamToString(request1.getInputStream());
    return responseBody;
}

  private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
   System.out.println(sb.toString());
    return sb.toString();

}}
```