# Facebook Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time

Tags: php, facebook

I have integrated the offline wall posting for the users of my website who have linked their FB accounts with there user details. I have stored there FB-id, FB-Access token in my database and by using the PHP-SDK libraries I had integrated the feed wall posting in the website. Everything worked very well with all users getting the messages on there facebook wall. But today all the things went in vain as it throws various kinds of error. I have been searching for more documents but can't find the exact relevant solution for this issues.

Lines of code i have used for FB-Wall Posting

```
             $usid=$pageinfo['user']['id_facebook'];
    $accestoken=$pageinfo['user']["facebook_accesstoken"];

        if($pageinfo['user']['user_fbtoken']=='1')

         $attachment =  array(
        'access_token' => $accestoken,
        'message' => "myTaste || real restaurant reviews, share your taste on myTaste",
        'name' => "My Favorite Restaurant is ".$business['name'].$business['location']['city']."-What is yours? ",
        'link' => $business['personal_url'],
        'description' => "", 
        'picture'=> "http://googima.com/images/mysite.gif"
        );  

        $facebook->api("/".$usid."/feed", "post",$attachment); 
    }
```

Error messages:

```
 Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time

 Uncaught OAuthException: (#210) User not visible thrown in /hsphere/local/home/mysite.com/include/3rdparty/facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php
```

The main idea of doing this offline wall posting is user is not going to asked for the FB login each time when do some reviews in the website. It need to post automatically by using the FB details that we have stored in the user table.

Comment: @ifaour: i have did the same way what have you mentioned in ur previous forum replies like EDIT:4,EDIT2. I have got the result yesterday and everything worked very well, but the today it throws the following errors.

Comment: Ah sorry for this! I thought that you are retrieving something! For posting you don't need the `offline_access` permission. The `publish_stream` is all that you need, and after that just remove the `access_token` from your array!

Comment: @ifaour: I have removed the access token from the array list and everything working fine upto this moment.I hope this will surely work let me check it once again by tomorrow at my work.Really i am very thankful to you for your ideas and assessments.You are always rocking in FB API.

Comment: for others like me - the straight answer is to use app_access_token instead of user_access_token and here's how to get app_access_token -https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/publishing-with-app-token/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you grant the `publish_stream` permission, no need for the `access_token`. So removing it and using something like this would work even without a valid session (just an example):

```
$params =  array(
    'message' => "Test Message",
    'picture'=> "http://path/to/image.jpg"
);  
$post_id = $facebook->api("/$uid/feed", "post",$params);
```

For more information refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814432/facebook-sharing-graph-api/4816134#4816134) (EDIT 4). Kudos to @zerkms for this info btw!

Comment: @ifaour: Still it throws other error now in the server, when i checked this feature by today morning.

Comment: @ifaour:Today morning i have checked the functionality, still it shows the following error set of codes.                                                         Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#210) User not visible thrown in /hsphere/local/home/mysite.com/include/3rdparty/facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php on line 543

Comment: @ifaour: i have more concerns  regarding feed post, because today my site is getting someother errors.When the user is logged into the system with his login details,he is able to post review and inturn the FB wall posting is taking place rightly. After sometimes, lets say after 4hr or 5hr , the same user tried to post some reviews, then it turns down the errors as shown below Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#210) User not visible thrown in /hsphere/local/home/mysite.com/facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php on line 543.So, Please let me know whether we need offline_access

Comment: @Anandhan: I've made a quick search about this error and I found [this](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=89029), it may help you. Also if you are appending the user's `access_token` I would recommend removing it.

Comment: @ifaour:I have removed the accesstoken from the array,but still it shows the user not visible thrown error. Let me explain what is happening, if x is logged in the website with user details and have (FB acount detail(test1) linked , on another hand the browser has other tab with some other FB acount (test2) loged in, at this time if the user from my site submit a review it throws the following error as user visible and also some exception.Can u please guide me to overcome this issue.

Comment: @Anandhan: you shouldn't allow this! you should check if you have a logged in user *x* (with fb *test1*) and the FB session is returning (*test2*) then you should ask the user to correct this if he is going to interact with Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Access token is not permanent in facebook oauth implementation. You need to renew it in the begin of your working session

More details at: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not using the FB login each time for the user to make there post there review in FBwall so i didn't have a way to reset the session at all times.So is anyother way to make it infinite expiry time.