# OAuth token Expires Time different between accounts

Tags: facebook, api, oauth

Strange issue, perhaps I'm missing something here.

In the process of making an app, when I take permission for my app, using my credentials, i get an OAuth token for 60 days.

But when my client takes an OAuth token for his app, using his account, he gets a token for 2 hours. [expires=6870]

I am taking the following permissions.

read_stream,publish_stream,user_groups

The script remains the same, just the app and the account changes.

Am I missing something here???

I have seen his app settings, it's same.

Comment: adding offline_access to the list, it gives my client access token expires = 4682

even less than before. (it gives me around 357 days!) [same script no change]

Comment: Which way of authentication are you using – client-side? If so, the token will be short-lived, and you have to exchange it for a long-lived one yourself, see https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: server-side

1. Using the same script (removed offline_access btw) i get 60 days, but my client, using an fb app he created & his credentials he gets only 2 hours

2. using renew token => ... grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=... i get an error "Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time"

3. And trying this => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827901/faceboook-error-validating-access-token-session-has-expired-at-unix-time ... i get error "(#200) This API call requires a valid app_id"

AND just FYI, am NOT using SDK, just simple old curl

Thanx for ur help

Answer (score 0):

first, forget about "offline_access", that permission is deprecated since months.

second, maybe this will help you, it worked for me in a project some weeks ago:
[How to extend access token validity since offline_access deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982025/how-to-extend-access-token-validity-since-offline-access-deprecation)

maybe you get 60 days because you are the admin of the app, but i don´t know for sure. fact is that nowadays a normal access token is valid for only 2 hours.

Comment: Please refer to my above comment,   
  
1. I have removed offline_access, not using it at all. AND just FYI, am NOT using SDK, just curl
  
2. the App under my login, for testing, and then gave permission from my website to the app. Then i installed same app on his website, he then created an app from his fb login on fb, and gave his permissions (server side), he is getting a 2 hr token
  
3. using renew token => "grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=" i get an error "Session has expired at unix time" this on his site, where my site is gettin new tokens
  
Thanx for ur help

Comment: you should take a look at the php sdk, it is easy to handle and since version 3.2.0 it includes a function "setExtendedAccessToken" - for extending the access token